# Hyperledger Iroha Build issue

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, hyperledger

I am tryin to build Hyperledger-Iroha on Windows 10 platform (Visual Studio 16 2019, Cmake, etc) w/o much luck. The problem is 'SOCI_postgresql_PLUGIN-NOTFOUND'!!! I get the following error message. All help much appreciated and Many thanks in advance.

```
 C:\Users\Tanis\OneDrive\Desktop\iroha>cmake -H. -Bbuild -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Tanis\OneDrive\Desktop\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake -G "Ninja"
-- -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-- -DTESTING=ON
-- -DUSE_BTF=OFF
-- -DBENCHMARKING=OFF
-- -DFUZZING=OFF
-- -DCOVERAGE=OFF
-- -DPACKAGE_ZIP=OFF
-- -DPACKAGE_TGZ=OFF
-- -DPACKAGE_RPM=OFF
-- -DPACKAGE_DEB=OFF
-- -DSANITIZE_THREAD=OFF
-- -DSANITIZE_ADDRESS=OFF
-- -DSANITIZE_MEMORY=OFF
-- -DSANITIZE_UNDEFINED=OFF
-- RapidJSON found. Headers: C:/Users/Tanis/OneDrive/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/share/rapidjson/../../include
-- Could NOT find soci (missing: SOCI_postgresql_PLUGIN)
-- Git repo pretty version: 1.2.0-rc.1-33-geccea5eb
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Tanis/OneDrive/Desktop/iroha/build

C:\Users\Tanis\OneDrive\Desktop\iroha>cmake --build build --target irohad -- -j8
ninja: error: 'SOCI_postgresql_PLUGIN-NOTFOUND', needed by 'bin/irohad.exe', missing and no known rule to make it

---
```